# For loop in JavaScript I want some knowledge about the program that is given below

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  var product = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      product * arr[i][j];
    }
  }

  return product;
}

const result = multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);

console.log(result);
```

Q1. What is `arr[i]`?
Q2. I just saw the arrays made like `var multiplyAll = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]` so I am not getting the point of the Array made in the above code I specified?

If any one could help me with understanding this code then the help would be much appreciated because I don't want to get into the next question without getting my basics cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is called with a *matrix*, i.e. a 2-dimensional array. In JavaScript this is represented as an array of arrays. The outer array has one entry per *row*, and each row itself is an array of values.

> Q1. what is arr[i] ?

It is one row in the matrix: the one with index `i`. It is an array, which is why you can specify another index for *that* array, like `arr[i][j]` It means: take the row at index `i` and from that array take the value at index `j`.

> Q2. I just saw the arrays made like `var multiplyAll = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]` so I am not getting the point of the Array made in the above code.

It creates a two dimensional array *on-the-fly*. While you can use such a *literal* to initialise a variable through the assignment operator (which you seem to understand), you can also provide it as argument for a function call. The corresponding parameter variable `arr` will then receive that as its initialisation value. So in a way it is *also* an assignment, just not with the `=` operator.

Comment: on point explanation sir. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what this function does is it receives a 2d-array (so that is an array of arrays). This means that `arr[i]` is an array itself; the first array in the outer array.

The concept of 2d arrays is quite useful, for example for grids or boards. Although at first glance they seem weird they are not too bad once you understand them. It helps to not cramp them into 1 line:

```
var multiplyAll = [
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6,7]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Q2: The array in `multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);` is being created as a function argument and not assigned to a variable. When you use `var array = [1, 2, 3]` the `[1, 2, 3]` part creates the array, the `var array =`  part is just used to assign the array to a variable. When the function `multiplyAll` is called the array `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]` is being passed in as the first argument so inside the function it is assigned to `arr`.

Q1: `arr[i]` is used to reference the 'i'th element in `arr`. For example if I had `var arr = [3, 5, 4]` and I used `arr[0]` it would reference the 0th (first) element in `arr` or `3`

Comment: thank you so much for your time but i still have some doubt about the program that are i still am not clear about passing arguments in the function as in the function above (arr) what is this argument doing. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

1. `arr[i]` is an array within the array i being the index
2. this function doesn't do anything because of this line `product * arr[i][j];` it's not changing the array just multiplying it by 1 "in the air"- without saving it to a variable
   and then the function just returns product which is always 1, that's why this function is wrong it just returns 1

Answer (score 0):

a function, takes in some sort of input, and does something, or returns something (this means that the function outputs something and you can use the function as part of an expression). this function returns the variable `product`.

the input is `arr`(the name doesn't matter) and it's supposed to be an array. An array is something like a list. for example `[1, 2, 3]` is a list of numbers. and you can get a specific index of that array by saying `arr[0]`, because arrays start at 0, `arr[0]` is the value 1.

You can have an array of strings `["hello", "world"]` and everything, so there's no reason way you can't have an array of arrays for example `[[1, 2], [3,4]]` in this array, `arr[0]` is the first value, which is [1,2], which itself is an array, meaning you can access the first value there by saying `arr[0][0]`.

ok, about the function specifically:

a variable named `product` is declared with the value `1`. it is a number.

and there's a loop that basically says "make a variable named `i` and set it to zero. keep looping and add 1 to the variable `i` until it `i` is not less than the length of the array anymore." this means that the first loop loops as many times as the length of the outer array.

and each time the variable i increases. and instead of a number `arr[0]`, you can put a variable in the brackets, so it's `arr[i]`. remember `arr` is an array of arrays, so `arr[i]` is another array.

this should answer question 1

inside this loop, there is another loop, which loops through the "inner" array. the logic for this is the same, just with a variable named `j`. these two loops mean that for every loop of the outer for loop, the inner for loop loops through all of the "inner" array.

inside the 2 for loops, you now have access to both `i` and `j`. this goes through all possible values. so if you were to console.log(i,j), it would print something like this

0 0

0 1

1 0

1 1

2 0

2 1

2 3

if you do `arr[i][j]` now, when all of the loops are finished, it should go through all of the values. it multiplies product by that value. (i think it's supposed to be `product *= arr[i][j]`). in the end, it will return all values multiplied together

I think I probably repeated many things you already knew but I think this explains everything.